# Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

After I upload a photo I want to pass the name and location of the file to a table called `pics` (which has a `pic_id` primary key attribute, `filename`, and `filepath`). I also want to store the `pic_id` uploaded into the users table, so essentially the `pic_id` in the `pics` table references the `pic_id` in the users table. However I get `Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (db . pics, CONSTRAINT pics_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pic_id) REFERENCES users (pic_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`.

PHP & SQL code:

```
$max = "
    SELECT pic_id 
      FROM profile_pics 
     WHERE pic_id = (
           SELECT MAX(pic_id) 
             FROM profile_pics
     )
";

$sql_update = "
    UPDATE users 
       SET pic_id = '$max'
     WHERE username = '$username'
";

$sql_insert = "
    INSERT INTO profile_pics (pic_id, filename, filepath) 
    VALUES ('' ,'$fileName', '$resized_file')
";
$results_insert = $conn->query($sql_insert);
if (!$results_insert) {
    exit ("Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Table Relationship between Users and Pics
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrRFy.png)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$max = "SELECT pic_id FROM profile_pics WHERE pic_id = (SELECT MAX(pic_id) FROM profile_pics)";
```

Does not actually give you the result in the variable `$max`. You have to execute the query and read the result.

Also you could just use

```
SELECT MAX(pic_id) AS pic_id FROM profile_pics
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely with this information:

> Remove `pic_id` from the insert query.

Inserting an empty into `pic_id` here will fail with the foreign key constraint. a NULL (which happens when the field is not specified) will lead to either an auto_increment value or a NULL insert, which depending on the constraint might work.

Also using your current code will fail when 2 people execute an insert at the same time: You are not using a transaction to control your `select max(pic_id)` and subsequent insert. 2 executions at the same time will lead to 2 users with the same `pic_id`

Comment: How can i insert the pic_id attributed to the user in the previous update statement?

Comment: If you execute `$sql_insert` first, mysql can return `last_insert_id`, thus removing the need for the `max` query. Use for example `$last_id = mysql_insert_id();` to get an auto increment last incremented value back.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: You can't insert a value into the child table unless that value already exists in the parent. Try inserting into profile_pics first, *then* update users.

(Also, the table names in your screen shot and error message don't seem to match those in your code snippet. Be careful of that.)

Comment: yeah i took out some attributes that werent relevant to this code so it was easier to understand. That being said I want to give the pic_id in pics the same value as the pic_id in users, do you know how I could do that?

Comment: `pic_id` is your primary key in `pic`. Make that column an autoincrement column and let the dbms generate the value for you, then retrieve it with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and insert that value into `users`.